# Do I need to include a target-audience disclaimer in this disputed answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

**Context**

Yesterday I posted [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/219945/62533), to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/219734/62533) on the development of LED illumination as an industrial product.

Possibly relevant is that my answer initially contained mention of, and Amazon links to, a specific product. This prompted a quite-valid 'spam' criticism in a comment, in response to which I edited out all reference to the product in question. I had debated about including the deleted material, and so didn't hesitate to remove it when challenged.

Anyways, also in comments, a moderator criticized some of the aspects of my answer.  I attempted to respond to this criticism, but the moderator was not mollified. In an effort to put an end to the back-and-forth, I posted an [admittedly snarky response](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219734/why-did-leds-take-so-long-to-appear-as-light-bulbs#comment472230_219945) (EDIT: now deleted at some point by someone other than myself), the audience of which I intended only to be the moderator in question.  The mod then edited my comment, verbatim, into the head of my answer.  I rolled back his edit; he re-rolled it back in, and so on.  After a couple of these back-and-forth cycles, he rolled the disclaimer back into the post and locked the answer as 'pending content dispute.'

**Questions**

Regardless of the interpersonal conflict underlying these events, I feel a disclaimer of this sort is superfluous. An expert in the field will likely read the answer and think, "Well, duh." A non-expert will hopefully read the answer and think, "Huh! Didn't know that."

My questions:

1. Is such a 'target-audience' disclaimer required for this question, per site policy?
2. If so, might I at least choose my own wording for it?

Comment: It's your wording.  I've pasted it there verbatim.  Are you saying that you didn't choose your words to begin with?

Comment: @NickAlexeev: You need to take a step back from this one. This is a blatant abuse of moderator power over a content issue. Unlock the post and leave it alone.

Comment: An edit war initiated by a mod? JFC.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Aren't people entitled to change their mind about their own wording? It's a Q&A site, not a legal dispute where people have to stick to everything they have said verbatim.

Comment: @DaveTweed you might consider keeping "moderator to moderator" comments out of the public eye? I always learnt "praise publicly, criticize privately". I am sure you mods have back channels. If you don't, you should.

Comment: @Floris: Yes, we have back channels, and we use them regularly. However, this needed to be said in the context of this post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Due to third-party intervention, the post has now been unlocked.

Further, after reflection, I felt the moderator in question had some good criticisms about my answer. I have [edited](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/219945/10) it accordingly, including working in a milder version of the 'target-audience disclaimer' from which the conflict arose.

Answer (score -11):

I didn't perceive that comment as a snark at my expense.

> 1. Is such a 'target-audience' disclaimer required for this question, per site policy?

Required?  No.

Is it a good idea to identify your target audience?  Yes, it is.  And it isn't superfluous.  Especially when your target audience is different from the default audience.

You *have* made the disclaimer.  I have only made it more conspicuous for the future readers.

> 2. If so, might I at least choose my own wording for it?

You have already chosen your own wording.  It's your wording.  I've pasted it there verbatim.

Comment: You can't just force your edit when the answer's author doesn't agree with it.

Comment: @MaximGi frankly - you can - and should, in some situations (blatant breach of site rules being one); still, the point is that *this wasn't such case and thus it wasn't warranted by anything*, and with that I do agree.

Comment: "blatant breach of site rules being one" [...] "this wasn't such case". This. Please, don't put my comment in another context to refute it, that's close to dishonesty ;)

Comment: @MaximGi  That's nowhere close to dishonesty.  The original text of your comment is nearby for anyone to read.  Besides, your comments aren't sacred text.